# display image and video in gridview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have implemented gridview in recyclerview to display image and videos with thumbnails.
I have used following code to fetch images in **`onBindView`** method

Getting images thumbnails using below code:

```
 bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(context
                        .getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), item.getImgId(),
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
```

Getting video thumbnails using below code:

```
  bitmap = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(context
                       .getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), item.getImgId(),
               MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
```

but every time i scroll view sticks(it takes some time to scroll down or up). i think it is because i am loading thumbnails in **`onBindView`** method.

help me improve this code so that it can be scrolled smoothly.
or any API to do it easily.

Comment: have you tried running the process of generating in separate thread instead of main thread ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put below code into the onCreate:

```
 imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter();
    imageAdapter.initialize();
```

and here is the Adapter for fetching images and video from the local storage check it out:

```
  public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        public ArrayList<ImageItem> images = new ArrayList<ImageItem>();

        public ImageAdapter() {
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        public void initialize() {
            images.clear();
            final String[] columns = {MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID};
            final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
            Cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns,
                    null, null, orderBy);


            int int_position = 0;
            Uri uri;
            Cursor cursor;
            int column_index_data, column_index_folder_name, column_id, thum;

            String absolutePathOfImage = null;
            uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

            String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, MediaStore.Video.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Video.Media._ID, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.DATA};

            cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, orderBy + " DESC");

            column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
            column_index_folder_name = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME);
            column_id = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID);
            thum = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.DATA);

            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                int id = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID);
                absolutePathOfImage = cursor.getString(column_index_data);
                Log.e("Column", absolutePathOfImage);
                Log.e("Folder", cursor.getString(column_index_folder_name));
                Log.e("column_id", cursor.getString(column_id));
                Log.e("thum", cursor.getString(thum));

                ImageItem obj_model = new ImageItem();
                obj_model.id = id;
                obj_model.thumb = cursor.getString(thum);
                images.add(obj_model);
            }

            if (imagecursor != null) {
                int image_column_index = imagecursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
                int count = imagecursor.getCount();
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
                    int id = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
                    ImageItem imageItem = new ImageItem();
                    imageItem.id = id;
                    lastId = id;
                    imageItem.img = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                            getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), id,
                            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
                    images.add(imageItem);
                }
                imagecursor.close();
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public void checkForNewImages() {
            //Here we'll only check for newer images
            final String[] columns = {MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID};
            final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
            Cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " > " + lastId, null, orderBy);
            int image_column_index = imagecursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
            int count = imagecursor.getCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
                int id = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
                ImageItem imageItem = new ImageItem();
                imageItem.id = id;
                lastId = id;
                imageItem.img = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                        getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), id,
                        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
                imageItem.selection = true; //newly added item will be selected by default
                images.add(imageItem);
            }
            imagecursor.close();
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return images.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.galleryitem1, null);
                holder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
                holder.ivVideoIcon = (ImageView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.ivVideoIcon);
                holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.itemCheckBox);
                holder.pbImageLoad = (ProgressBar) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.pbImageLoad);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            ImageItem item = images.get(position);
            holder.checkbox.setId(position);
            holder.imageview.setId(position);


            if (item.thumb != null) {
                /*Picasso.with(AndroidCustomGalleryActivity.this)
                        .load("file" + item.thumb)
                        .into(holder.imageview);*/
                holder.ivVideoIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Glide.with(AndroidCustomGalleryActivity.this).load(Uri.fromFile(new File(item.thumb)))
                        .listener(new RequestListener<Uri, GlideDrawable>() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onException(Exception e, Uri model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                holder.pbImageLoad.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                return false;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, Uri model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                holder.pbImageLoad.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                return false;
                            }
                        })
                        .skipMemoryCache(false)
                        .into(holder.imageview);
            } else {
//                holder.imageview.setImageBitmap(item.img);
                if (item.img != null) {
                    holder.ivVideoIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    item.img.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                    Glide.with(AndroidCustomGalleryActivity.this).load(stream.toByteArray()).asBitmap().listener(new RequestListener<byte[], Bitmap>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onException(Exception e, byte[] model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            holder.pbImageLoad.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, byte[] model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            holder.pbImageLoad.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            return false;
                        }
                    }).skipMemoryCache(false).into(holder.imageview);
                }
            }
            holder.checkbox.setChecked(item.selection);
            return convertView;
        }
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageview;
        ImageView ivVideoIcon;
        CheckBox checkbox;
        ProgressBar pbImageLoad;
    }

    class ImageItem {
        boolean selection;
        int id;
        Bitmap img;
        String thumb;
    }
```